# Using regular expression find and replace in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, replace, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL workbench query window.

I want to find all the numbers in the query window using a regular expression and surround them with parentheses.

I'm using `[0-9]+$` as the matching pattern which finds the numbers correctly but I'm not able to figure out the correct replace expression.

e.g. in the query window, if there's a number `10` it should be replaced by `(10)` in my case.

Can anybody help me out with this?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that within an edit tab. Best would be to copy the contents to a standard text editor (e.g. Notepad++), make the replacement, and copy back to Workbench.

Comment: @FDavidov - thanks. I think that's what needs to be done. Having that feature in MySQL workbench would have simplified things a bit though.